# Tree Table binding in QUnit test

Tags: sapui5, qunit

I am faced with the issue while implementing the QUnit test for my application which uses TreeTable from SAP UI5 library.

```
 <TreeTable id="TreeTableBasic" rows="{path:'/statementStatistics', parameters: {arrayNames:['statements']}}" selectionMode="MultiToggle" enableSelectAll="false" ariaLabelledBy="title">
```

My tree table is as above. Every thing looks good, my app and OPA5 tests runs well until I start to implement the Qunit test for it.

With the same MockServer, same mock data with OPA5 tests, but in Qunit perspective, It throws errors like

> Path path:'/statementStatistics', parameters: {arrayNames:['statements']} must start with a /

My mockdata is a json like

[image]

For More information about the console log on browser's debugger tool

[image]

Thank you for your help.